# Runtimes supported by containerd apart from runC?

Tags: docker, linux-containers, containerd, runc

Does containerd support any other runtimes apart from runC?

Further, the [containerd](https://containerd.io/) site says, "An industry-standard container runtime with an emphasis on simplicity, robustness and portability". Does this refer to any specific standard like the OCI or CRI.

Answer (score 1):

From: [github.com/containerd/containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd)

> ### Runtime Requirements
>
> Runtime requirements for containerd are very minimal. Most interactions with the Linux and Windows container feature sets are handled via [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) and/or OS-specific libraries (e.g. [hcsshim](https://github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim) for Microsoft).

---

From: [github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim](https://github.com/Microsoft/hcsshim)

> ## hcsshim
>
> This package contains the Golang interface for using the Windows [Host Compute Service](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/introducing-the-host-compute-service-hcs/ba-p/382332) (HCS) to launch and manage [Windows Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/). It also contains other helpers and functions for managing Windows Containers such as the Golang interface for the Host Network Service (HNS).

Regarding the OCI part of your question:

> #### OCI Runtime Specification
>
> containerd fully supports the OCI runtime specification for running containers. We have built in functions to help you generate runtime specifications based on images as well as custom parameters.
>
> You can specify options when creating a container about how to modify the specification.
>
> ```
> redis, err := client.NewContainer(context, "redis-master", containerd.WithNewSpec(oci.WithImageConfig(image)))
> ```